# How to get the avg for groups i created SQL Query

Tags: sql, qsqlquery

my SQL code not working (syntax error at or near "FROM")
i need my final table to be three rows. the average of standard_amt_usd for the three total group i created from Total column. where is my mistake?

```
select avg(orders.standard_amt_usd), orders.total
, case when orders.total between 1 and 100 then "1 to 100"
when orders.total between 101 and 300 then " 101 to 300"
else " +500 "

FROM orders;
group by total
```

Comment: I don't know  qsql but in SQL you shouldn't have a semicolon after FROM orders (because the command still has the GROUP BY), and your group by should also include the case when... expression (because it is not aggregated)

Comment: also, in general, strings are enclosed in single quotes, not double quotes (but it may be allowed in qsqlquery)

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `END` statement after all your cases.

Like this:

```sql
SELECT AVG(orders.standard_amt_usd), orders.total,
CASE
    WHEN orders.total BETWEEN 1 AND 100 THEN '1 to 100'
    WHEN orders.total BETWEEN 101 AND 300 THEN '101 to 300'
    ELSE '+500'
END AS OrderTotals
FROM orders
GROUP BY total;
```

**Comments:**

- Always use single quotes (`'`) with SQL not double (`"`).
- Your semicolon was at the end of the `FROM` statement. Put it after `GROUP` like I did above.

Feel free to refer to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp)

Comment: it is working now. but i need just three rows, the total avg for group one  1 to 100 and group 2 101 to 300 and +500 .

Comment: You need to declare the ELSE statement each case and as Nicolas mentioned do not forget about the END statement.

Comment: it is not working. can you write what you mean?

Comment: Be aware that @Pythona has many symptoms of a [help vampire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258279/4194079). Your answer is already good as is +1.